# Duplicate Videos in YouTube Playlist

Tags: youtube

I uploaded a video only one time in my YouTube channel and added it in a Private Playlist but I can see that video has two copies (duplicated) and when I delete one copy the other copy is deleted as well automatically.

How to solve this issue and make sure it will not happen again in the future, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the duplicate video from the playlist, click on the 3-dots of the video and select Remove from this playlist.

[image]